# Looking for a short and relatively easy campaign to run as a beginner DM

Tags: pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, new-gm, published-adventures

I'm relatively new to playing Pathfinder and D&D --only a couple of  months-- and the group I play with wants everyone to DM at least one or two sessions so everyone gets a chance to play.

Can anyone recommend any premade but relatively short (5-10 hours) adventures/campaigns for Pathfinder? We have between 4 and 7 players, and it can be a serious or humorous campaign for any level (the group usually makes new characters for each campaign).

Comment: Possibly helpful, but not answer-worthy: ["Any good premade campaigns for beginners?"](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14163/4398) It's for D&D 3.5, but 3.5 and Pathfinder are similar enough that their content is sometimes used interchangeably, so maybe this is worth a look-see.

Comment: As this is a product recommendation question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Comment: Putting this on  hold for a moment. @Ren, Paizo (and others) have published literally hundreds of adventures for Pathfinder that could take a group 5-10 hours to play. Please add more details to your question that would focus it down to where there might be a best answer.

Comment: @mxyzplk Did you mean to make this system-recommendation? This is pretty specifically a Pathfinder thing.

Comment: Yes I did, we use that tag for any "*-recommendation" question as they all go by the same rules, see [meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/has-system-recommendation-grown-too-big-for-its-britches/2713#2713) for more. No sense having "adventure-recommendation" and "supplement-recommendation" and "whatever-recommendation." Feel free and liven up that meta discussion though.

Comment: Related if you want all the short adventures to just be part of one campaign: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22782/methods-for-round-robin-style-dming and http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22584/reward-distribution-and-story-continuity-with-rotating-players-gms/

Answer (score 4):

If you've already worked your way through the [Pathfinder Beginner Box](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/products/beginnerbox) adventure Black Fang's Dungeon, paizo have the 4 [Beginner Box Bash demos](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8q4o) that run at a few hours each, and can be run independently. These will be good if anyone else wants to try GMing, which is what I've been doing.

The [the beginner box GM kit](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8p2l?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Beginner-Box-GM-Kit) has an additional adventure that can follow on from Black Fang's dungeon, or run independently. It also contains details and advice for using pre-written adventures.

The Beginner Box Game Master's Guide has a lot of information for creating a simple adventure and a pre-drawn map (that fits on the included folding map mat) that you can play with to knock something together easily.

I'm working my way through all of this material with a group as a new GM and it's working great for us.

I've had a look at one of the Pathfinder Adventure paths (Carrion Crown), and their adventure paths run from first level, so I would recommend investigating [the Rise of the Runelords](http://paizo.com/pathfinder/adventurePath/riseOfTheRunelords) Adventure path. I've not tried it yet, but it looks like some of the Beginner Box Bash stories will work into its story; it's going to be the next step we'll take when we're finished with the Beginner Box material.

Comment: The only Adventure Path from Paizo I have played is _Howl of the Carrion King_, but I recommend it for everyone. Good fun with a bit of everything: combat, social conflict, strategy...

Comment: The good thing about Adventure Paths is that they give you everything you need, and they take the characters of your players from level 1 up to (almost) whatever level you want / can play (usually around 15ish).